# Titanfall "I've seen it all achievement" still track if you regenerate (prestige)

Tags: achievements, titanfall

At level 50, I've unlocked all equipment for the "All the Hardware" achievement and kept track of the levels I've played so far but i want to make sure I can now regenerate.

Looking around I've found a lot of people say "it's probably fine" and one person say "it's not fine" but with no more explanation.

Anyone have any experience of this or any proper evidence?

Comment: Well, I've regenerated so I'll let everyone know if it works or not in the next week or so... SCIENCE! ;)

Comment: If it's anything like the achievements for doing all IMC and Militia campaign missions, then it will include levels done pre-regenerate.  I regenerated, and played a few levels and that achievement popped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the counter achievements carry across generations.

The only one that doesn't is "Unlock Everything", which I think is badly worded. You have to have everything unlocked at once, so regenerating wipes out your progress.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I've still not managed it as RL got in the way. Hopefully it will work as you suggest! :)

Comment: @FrostbiteXIII "I've seen it all" popped for me on Gen 4 after a run of Pilot Hunter matches - I didn't play any other mode since regen, so I must have kept track of my old games. With the new patch (due today) it should track your games on each map in the stats.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - I'll check tonight. Might finally be able to delete my spreadsheet then! ;)